# WPF形式のWindowsのデスクトップアプリからの外部（xamarin）UWPアプリの起動についての質問

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Visual Studioで、WPF形式のWindowsのデスクトップアプリ（仮称：A.exe）を作ったのですが、機能的な制限があって、当方がXamarinで作ったUWPのアプリ（仮称：B.exe）を起動する必要があります。

昔ながらの方法で、A.exe内で

```
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            //pInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";

            pInfo.FileName = "B.exe";

            var proc = Process.Start(pInfo);
            proc.WaitForExit();
```

と呼びだそうとしたのですが、そもそも、パッケージ化したインストーラーでB.exeをしたので、インストール先のパスが怪しく、色々調べていると、URI？を使ってLaunchUriAsyncで起動すべきなのかと混乱しております。
上記のWPFのプロジェクト内からは「LaunchUriAsync」が使えないみたいで・・・。

大変恐縮ですが、何方か、WPF形式形式のアプリからの正しい起動の仕方をお教えいただけないでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事あたりが参考になるかもしれません。[DesktopBridge アプリで UWP アプリと Win32 アプリの連携方法](https://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/2018/02/10/174735), [コマンドラインからUWPアプリを起動する](https://studist.tech/launch-uwp-via-commandline-ba6df9798b3d), [Windows 10でコマンドラインからUWPアプリを開く方法](https://genuine-lamps.com/ja/windows/15971-how-to-open-uwp-apps-from-the-command-line-on-windows-10.html), [How to launch a Windows Universal App from winform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41887366/9014308), [Windows 10でUWPアプリを起動する方法](https://ascii.jp/elem/000/001/832/1832835/)

Comment: お教え頂き、ありがとうございます。　早速確認してみます。